# Getting a CompilationException in Weblogic Server 10.3.0.0. How to fix it?

Tags: html, jsp, weblogic

I am getting an

> weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException

in my JSP file deployed in Weblogic Server 10.3.0.0.

```
FileName.jsp:2:1 The type Object is ambiguous
<!DOCTYPE html>
^--------------
</head>
------^
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.compilePage(JavelinxJSPStub.java:328)
----
----
```

I even tried by removing the DOCTYPE but still getting the same error as above :

```
FileName.jsp:2:1 The type Object is ambiguous
<html>
^-----
</head>
------^
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JavelinxJSPStub.compilePage(JavelinxJSPStub.java:328)
----
----
```

Don't know why this error is coming. Does anyone have any idea? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an import conflict. I resolved it by changing the relative import statements in my jsp code with absolute import statements.

E.g. If I want to use ArrayList instead of importing java.util.* (Relative Import), import java.util.ArrayList(Absolute Import).